# How do I create a temporal table in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I want to know how to create a system-versioned table, when I want to create a new temporal table in SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-1-creating-tables-and-modifying-data):

> In order to make a table a system-versioned table it needs the
>   following:
>
> - A primary key
> - The table option SYSTEM_VERSIONING to be set to ON
> - Two non-nullable DATETIME2() columns representing the    start and end of the row’s validity period
>
>   - The start column should be marked with the option GENERATED ALWAYS AS    ROW START
>   - The end column should be marked with the option GENERATED ALWAYS AS    ROW END
> - Designation of the period columns: PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME    (, )
> - A linked history table (which SQL Server can create for you) to hold    the past states of modified rows

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this two links:

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/first-look-system-versioned-temporal-tables-part-1-creating-tables-and-modifying-data

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manub22/archive/2015/06/30/temporal-data-with-system-versioned-tables-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/06/15/temporal-data-support-in-sql-server-2016-part-1/

```
    USE [TestManDB]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Department 
    (
    DepartmentID        int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
    DepartmentName      varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    ManagerID           int NULL, 

    ValidFrom           datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL, 
    ValidTo             datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   NOT NULL,   

    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (
    ValidFrom, 
    ValidTo
    )   
    )
    WITH ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ); -- No History table name given here
    GO
```

credits to the link above for the source code.

Comment: @ManojPandey , i found that online and shared here :) perfect blog post for the question above.. you're welcome and thank you too for your post. :)

Answer (score 1):

By using System_versioning=ON it will automatically assign system table name , but if you want to explicitly mentioned your system table like below

```
--create table or use existing table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [updated_at] [datetime] NULL
)

GO
--Adding additional field for temporal tables
alter table dbo.table1
add start_time DATETIME2 generated always as row start hidden default sysutcdatetime()
    ,end_time DATETIME2 generated always as row end hidden default sysutcdatetime()
    ,period for system_time (start_time, end_time)
go

--enable system versioning
alter table dbo.table1
set (system_versioning = ON ( history_table = dbo.table1_history))
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to sample cases at [how to create temporal tables in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2016/create-sql-server-2016-temporal-table.aspx) according to each scenario.

The simplest form is creating a new SQL table as temporal table as follows

```
create table sampleTable (
  IdColumn int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered,
  Code varchar(5),
  CurrentValue varchar(100),
  SysStartTime datetime2 Generated Always as Row Start Not Null,
  SysEndTime datetime2 Generated Always as Row End Not Null,
  Period for System_Time (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
 )
 with (System_Versioning = ON)
```

This will create a database table named sampleTable and its corresponding history table in the current database